# How to generate random color and affect all the activity?

Tags: java, android

I am working on app that required background music and color,So my question is when I generate color from main activity,it should affect all my activities similarly with background sound.I added sound and random colours but it remain in main activity which I don't want,please let me know how to code this,Hope I will get answer soon thanks advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe you could have a custom Activity that all other activities extends. This custom activity would be in charge of managing the background colour and music.